# BCP Utility is failing in SQL Server due to special character in Password

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

When I am trying to import data from one database to our database it is constantly failing. I am quite sure username and password has not changed. My password is XXXXXX. Is it due to special character $ in password? If so how to handle it. I am using SQL Server 2017 version.

Comment: What's error?  Also, can you show us the code you are using to run BCP?  Obviously change the names and the password, but leave the "$".

Comment: It is telling login failed with this message SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'x'.

Comment: This command I am using bcp DatabaseName.Schema.Target_Table in "Datafile.txt" -b 5000 -n -S Host,1433 -U User -P L@ik8$Lp. My Datafile.txt is already created and also I am using this command since last 1 year and we are using a new database since last 1 week and getting this error while this BCP as a test run for first time in new database.

Comment: Does user `x` have a backslash (\\) or at symbol (@) in it? Is it possible you're trying to use SQL Login authentication for a Windows/Domain account?

Comment: The "@" is more likely a problem than the "$".  In any event: 1) confirm that you can login with this password yourself with Management Studio (SSMS) or whatever you use to manage/test/access your SQL Servers.  Then 2) try putting the password in quotes (i.e., `P "L@ik8@Lp"`)

Comment: [Edit] all clarifications directly into the question please.

Comment: Yes I can login in SSMS using this Password since the database is created. I have tried suing Double quotes but no use

Comment: Are you running the bcp.exe command from a Command Prompt or from a PowerShell prompt? That password wouldn't be a problem in a Command Prompt but the `$` character would be a problem for PowerShell - in that case surround the password with single quotes, i.e.: `'L@ik8$Lp'`

Comment: Thanks @AlwaysLearning Your suggestion worked :)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - can you create the answer? That helped me out as well (putting the password in single quotes).

Comment: Btw, this was my updated python code after applying the suggest solution above. In case it helps others

`bcp_cmd = f'/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp "select * from mytable" queryout "{bcp_data_filename}" -S {host} -n -b 10000000 -U "{login}" -P \'{password}\' `